# Chemical Engineering Simulation Software?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for chemical engineering simulation software similar to Aspentech Hysys for modelling of heat exchangers, pipeline flow and other material and energy balances.
 I can't seem to find anything through the software centre that is near to this great software. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do any of these meet requirements: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source process simulator called [DWSIM](http://dwsim.inforside.com.br). You can also try [COCO simulator](http://www.cocosimulator.org) under Wine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Cain**

[image: Install via the software center]

Also can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install cain
```